# Jqgrid column header buttons is not displaying properly

Tags: jqgrid

I have a buttons and column names in the jqgrid(v4.4.4.4) column headers, i have added styles for my column headers. The buttons and column names are not displaying fully instead displaying partially[image]

here the column header values are improper. Not sure where will be the mistake. Please help me to achieve displaying complete headers. Thanks.

UPDATED:
version : v4.4.4 .My code,

```
    $(function () {
    var Role = $("#hiddenRole").val();
    $("#ProgramListGird").jqGrid({
        url: '/Home/programGrid',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'Get',
        colNames: ['id', 'Program', 'Unit', 'Active?', '<input type="button" style="display: inline-block; padding: 3px 12px;margin: 0px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;border-radius: 4px;overflow:visible;border:1px solid #444444;color: #000;box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px 0px #cccccc;" id="addNewProgramId" value="Add New Program" onclick= "addNewProgram()"/>'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, name: 'id', index: 'id', hidden: true },
            {
                name: 'ProgramDesc', index: 'ProgramDesc', editable: true
                ,editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: programDescValidation
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'UnitID', index: 'UnitID', editable: true, edittype: 'select',
                formatter: 'select', editoptions: { value: "Unit1:Unit1 ; Unit2/3:Unit2/3" },
                editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: dupicateRecordValidation
                }
            },
            {
                name: 'InActive', index: 'InActive', editable: true, formatter: 'select',
                stype: 'select', edittype: 'select', editoptions: { value: "false:No;true:Yes" }
            },
            {             

                sortable: false, align: "center", class: "button",
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObj) {                   
                    var cBtn = '<input type="button" style="display: inline-block; padding: 3px 12px;margin: 0px 0px;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal;text-align: center;white-space: nowrap;border-radius: 4px;overflow:visible;border:1px solid #444444;color: #000;box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px 0px #cccccc;" value="Save Changes" onclick= "saveChanges(' + "'" + rowObj.id + "'" + '\)"/>'
                        return cBtn;

                }
            }
        ],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 3,
        rowList: [3, 6, 9, 12],
        height: '100%',
        //width: outerwidth,
        //shrinkToFit: false,
        scrollerbar: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Program' + " " + Role,
        //loadonce: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        //editurl: '/Home/programGridSave',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        hidegrid: false,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,       
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            rowSelect(id);
        },

    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, cancel: false, reload: false, refresh: false }),
    $("#ProgramListGird").jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager',
        {
            edit: false, add: false, save: false, cancel: false, reload: false, refresh: false, restoreAfterSelect: false, 
        });
});
```

JSON data returned from /Home/programGrid,

```
public JsonResult programGrid(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)    {
programModel.id = "001";
programModel.ProgramDesc = "A";
programModel.InActive = true;
programModel.UnitID = "Unit1";
programModelList.Add(programModel);

programModel = new ProgramModel();
programModel.id = "002";
programModel.ProgramDesc = "B";
programModel.InActive = true;
programModel.UnitID = "Unit1";
programModelList.Add(programModel);

int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
int pageSize = rows;
var results = programModelList.Select(emp => new
{
    emp.id,
    emp.InActive,
    emp.ProgramDesc,
    emp.UnitID,
});
int totalRecords = results.Count();
var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
{
    results = results.OrderByDescending(s => s.id);
    results = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
else
{
    results = results.OrderBy(s => s.id);
    results = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
var jsonData = new
{
    total = totalPages,
    page,
    records = totalRecords,
    rows = results
};
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

Comment: One can't help you just based on the picture. You should post code, which you use and include the information about the version and the fork which you use. The mostly effective would be if you post JSFiddle demo, which reproduces the problem. One could include the modified demo in the answer on your question.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks for your feedback. Please find my updated code and version.

Comment: You use **retro version** 4.4.4, which is 4 years old. Your question is mostly about CSS problems. Which version of jQuery UI and jQuery you use? Which is your main web browser? jqGrid 4.4.4 was published at the time of Chrome 24, Firefox 18, IE9 (IE10 only on Windows 8). We have now Chrome 55, Firefox 50.1, Microsoft Edge 38, IE11. Do you believe that the usage of such old version of jqGrid is the good idea in case of usage modern web browsers? In any way I could try to help you later (about 2 hours later), because I'm busy now. You need mostly fix CSS rules from old `ui.jqgrid.css`

Comment: @Oleg: No problem I will for your answer. FYI, I am using IE 11 and visual studio 2015 I downloaded jQuery.Jqgrid v4.4.4 from NuGet package Manager. Kindly suggest me which version of jqgrid to be used with IE 11  for better performance along with ur answer. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you to uninstall old [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) 4.4.4 NuGet package and to use [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) 4.13.5 instead. I'll write my answer now, but I can give you more advices if you include an example of JSON data returned from `/Home/programGrid` (2 rows of test data would be enough). Moreover, it's better to use `loadonce: true` option if you don't have really large dataset (for example >10000 rows).

Comment: @Oleg: Included code as you suggested. Thanks for comments.

Comment: @Oleg: As you suggested i have uninstalled old jQuery.jqGrid 4.4.4 and installed  free-jqGrid 4.13.5 from NuGet package. Can u pls suggest what are all the declarations need to be included in my html page since i am getting "Object doesn't support property or method 'jqGrid' " Error.

Comment: Look at [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and [this one](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/examples/index.html) for code examples. In general you need just include `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` (or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) after `jquery.min.js` and create jqGrid *after* both are loaded. You should verify that the Paths (URLs), which you use, are correct and you include only 4.13.5 files (css and js) and no old 4.4.4 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use retro version 4.4.4, which is 4 years old. Your question is mostly about CSS problems. Which version of jQuery UI and jQuery you use? Which is your main web browser? jqGrid 4.4.4 was published at the time of Chrome 24, Firefox 18, IE9 (IE10 only on Windows 8). We have now Chrome 55, Firefox 50.1, Microsoft Edge 38, IE11. Do you believe that the usage of such old version of jqGrid is the good idea in case of usage modern web browsers? I would strictly recommend you to update jqGrid 4.4.4 to free jqGrid 4.13.5 (or to 4.13.6, which will be published next days). You will don't have the problem, which you try to solve.

You you really can't upgrade jqGrid 4.4.4 to more recent version, then you can fix old `ui.jqgrid.css` by overriding some CSS rules:

```css
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div { height: auto; }
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th { height: auto; }
```

You can include `<style> ... </style>` with the rules after `<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../ui.jqgrid.css" >`.

Comment: Awesome. Working fine. Thanks a lot. Not sure the why the jqgrid icons are duplicated in my screen. eg: custom validation popup close button is overridden/duplicated. I have referred ur answers in others post but not found solution for my case. Thanks.